# Seaborn: Is there a better way to wrap the text in my bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, word-wrap

I am writing a function for bar plots and have encountered another small problem. I have some ytick labels that are too long, causing my y axis label not able to be seen. I'm only able to see the y label when I drastically decrease the size of the ytick labels.

```
def bar_plot(data, x, y, title):
    sns.set_style('darkgrid')
    data = data.sort_values(ascending=False, by=x)
    data = data.head(n=10)
    if (data[x]>1000000).any():
        data[x] = data[x] / 1000000
        ax = sns.barplot(data=data, x=x, y=y)
        ax.set_title(title, size=35)
        ax.set_xlabel(x + ' ($ Millions)', size=15)
        ax.set_ylabel(y, size=15)
        ax.set_yticklabels(data[y].head(n=10), wrap=True)

    else:
       ax = sns.barplot(data=data, x=x, y=y)
       ax.set_xlabel(x, size=15)
       ax.set_ylabel(y, size=15)
       ax.set_title(title, size=35)
       ax.set_yticklabels(data[y].head(n=10), wrap=True)
```

I have tried `ax.set_yticklabels(data[y].head(n=10), wrap=True)` to wrap the text. While it works, it doesn't wrap the text enough. Is there a way to tell `wrap=True` to wrap after x amount of characters? I've tried googling this but couldn't quite find anything that works.

**Edit**

The format of the dataframe that I am working with is similar to

```
Client Name            Col 1      Col 2      Col 3      Col 4       Col 5
Some name              51,235.00  nan        23,423.00  12,456.00   654.00
Some long company name 152.00     5,626.00   nan        82,389.00   5,234.00
Name                   12,554.00  5,850.00   1,510.00   nan         12,455.00
Company                12,464.00  nan        752.00     1,243.00    1,256.00
Long Company Name      12,434.00  78,915.00  522.00     2,451.00    6,567.00
```

Comment: wrap=True will wrap at the figure boundaries. But you can use the `textwrap` module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) pointed out, you can use the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module to do this, specifically useful would be [`textwrap.fill()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill):

> `textwrap.fill(text[, width[, ...]])`
>
> > Wraps the single paragraph in text so every line is at most `width` characters long, and returns a single string containing the wrapped paragraph. `fill()` is shorthand for
> >
> > `"\n".join(wrap(text, ...))`

Although you will need to call this on each label separately with something like

```py
ax.set_yticklabels([textwrap.fill(e, width) for e in data[y].head()])
```

---

### Edit

Here is a more complete example to show the usage:

```py
import textwrap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = {'Client Name': ['Some Name', 'Some long company name', 'Name',
            'Company', 'Long Comany Name'],
      'Col 1': [51235, 152, 12554, 12464, 12434]}
data = pd.DataFrame(df)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)


ax.set_yticklabels(data['Client Name'].head())
plt.show()
```

This will show the following

[image]

whereas

```py
ax.set_yticklabels([textwrap.fill(e, 7) for e in data['Client Name'].head()])
plt.show()
```

will show something more like

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of the for loop? When using it I am getting a `Key Error`. However, when I remove it,         `ax.set_yticklabels([textwrap.fill(data[y].head(n=10), 20)]) `, I am getting another error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'`. My original simple solution of just using `wrap=True` could suffice if I cannot get this to work.

Comment: @messy748 The purpose of the for loop is because `textwrap.fill()` takes a single string and returns a string with newline characters such that no line exceeds `width`. I tested it with an example data frame and it worked, if you can post a portion of your data frame (even 5 rows) I will modify it to work with your data

Comment: @messy748 Perhaps the edit with a complete example will clarify the usage

Comment: I'm following what you are saying, but I am still getting a key error, `KeyError: 0` from this segment of the code: `.head()[i]`. I suppose that I still dont quite understand what the `[i]` is referring to. This is the same error that I was originally getting. The dataframe that I am working with is simply one column of client names (which is what is being plotted on the y axis) and then nine numeric columns. In total, it is 10 columns and roughly 8k rows. If that is not enough information, I could create a censored dataframe to replicate what I am working with,

Comment: @messy748 `.head()[i]` is to iterate over the dataframe elements and pass each one individually to `textwrap.fill()`, I used list comprehension to make it more succinct. If you could post something to show at least the format of your dataframe I will modify my example to use that instead

Comment: I made an edit to give an example of something that I am working with. Hope it helps

Comment: @messy748 I suspect the issue is either with some versioning problem or in what value your `y` variable has - try using `ax.set_yticklabels([textwrap.fill(data['Client Name'][i], 7) for i in range(5)])` *exactly* and see if it gives you a `Key Error` still.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting `KeyError: 0`

Comment: @messy748 what does `ax.set_yticklabels([textwrap.fill(e, 7) for e in data['Client Name']]` give you?

Comment: That does work! However, it did wrap the text mid-word. I had to modify it to `textwrap.fill(e, 20)` and now it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`textwrap` seems easy to use, but it splits the sentence at a predetermined number of characters. Here is a function to insert a newline symbol (`\n`) every `n` words. You can then use `out` as labels x- (or y-) axis tick marks. It might also be wise to avoid any unnecessary package dependencies.

```
Lst = ['You can never understand one language until you understand at least two.',
       'Language is the blood of the soul into which thoughts run and out of which they grow.']
InsertNewlines = lambda lst, n=2: '\n'.join([' '.join(lst[i:i + n]) for i in range(0, len(lst), n)]) # n=words to keep together
out = [InsertNewlines(s.split()) for s in Lst]
```

Output:

```
['You can\nnever understand\none language\nuntil you\nunderstand at\nleast two.',
 'Language is\nthe blood\nof the\nsoul into\nwhich thoughts\nrun and\nout of\nwhich they\ngrow.']
```

Answer (score 0):

from the answer of William Miller:

its better to change this part:

```
ax.set_yticklabels([textwrap.fill(e, 7) for e in data['Client Name'].head()])
plt.show()
```

you should change it to:

```
ax.set_yticklabels([textwrap.fill(e, 7) for e in data['Client Name']])
plt.show()
```

and second make sure you import textwrap