# create a file containing both printouts and plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a list of dataframes and a list of jsons, I want to get the df plots and jsons into one nice file (pdf or jpeg),
so far I added the json as the title of the plot and this works well enough for short strings (see below) but it gets problematic with longer jsons and I would like to add them as simple prints and not the titles, any ideas?

Here is what I have:

```
lodf = [pd.DataFrame([-1*x for x in range(20)]), pd.DataFrame(range(20))]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[16,2*len(lodf)])

for i, df0 in enumerate(lodf):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(len(lodf), 1, i+1)
    df0.plot(style='.', ms=8, ax=ax)
    ax.set_ylabel("YYY")
    ax.set_title('I want this as a print out since it is a long json', wrap=True)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=0.6)
plt.savefig('just_an_example.pdf')
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Do you have `LaTex` installed? If not, would you be interested in an answer which uses it?

Comment: sure,  always happy to try something new

Comment: Are the json strings to be interspersed with the plots or should they be grouped together?

Comment: grouped. json then a graph and again json and a graph and again...

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, do you want *one* json string and then a graph, or *multiple* json strings and then a graph?

Comment: one json, that might be very long

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the method outlined in my answer?

Comment: no. sorry for that

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to check in case you had and had further questions

Comment: Do let me know if you do get a chance to try it, I'm curious to know if it works well for your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a `LaTex` `tabular` environment to control the wrapping, something like this

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams["text.usetex"] = True

figsize = [10, 6]
plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
string = "string string string string string string string string string "
strings = [string]
for i in range(1, 6):
    strings.append(strings[i-1]+string)

plt.title(r'\begin{tabular}{p{'+str(figsize[0])+'in}} '+strings[5]+' \end{tabular}')
plt.show()
```

Would wrap the title at the figure boundaries:

[image]

Of course this is not the simplest way to wrap text (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59315998/10659910)), but this allows for finer control of the formatting than most other methods. For example, if you want to format some code you could do the following

```py
figsize = [10, 6]
plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
code = 'def function(arg1, arg2, arg3, kwarg1=None, kwarg2=None): \n\t print(arg1) '+
       '\n\t print(arg2) \n\t print(arg3)'
table = code.replace("\n", "\\\\").replace("\t", "\hspace{1cm}")
plt.title(r'\ttfamily \begin{tabular}{p{'+str(figsize[0])+'in}}'+table+'\end{tabular}')
plt.show()
```

Which gives

[image]

The reason I'm using the `LaTex` method is to allow more advanced formatting of the strings - allowing code to be formatted as code in any matplotlib text method (`title()`, `xlabel()`/`ylabel()`, `text()`, etc).